# List all items overdue or due within n days

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, excel-tables

Column J (Status) I have the following options:

- Overdue
- Due Within 30 Days
- Due within 90 Days
- Ok

Column C is the corresponding 'Action'.

Column F is the 'Team Name' - it is the same down the whole column as each sheet is team specific.

I have the above across 7 different sheets within the same workbook (they need to be on separate sheets so cannot be merged). The layout for each is the same but they relate to different teams.

**What I need to do is include a summary table that will show:**

**1. What actions are either 'Overdue' or 'Due Within 30 Days'**

**2. What team these actions relate to**

I can't figure out the best way to do this...

Example data below. This would be replicated across multiple sheets for each team.

```
Action Achieved Frequency Team   LastReviewDate DaysToDue Status
(BLANK ROW - ACTION CATEGORY HEADER)
1.1    Yes      Annually  Team1  01/03/2019     -18       Overdue
1.2    Yes      Annually  Team1  01/11/2019     227       Over 90 Days
1.3    Yes      Annually  Team1  01/11/2019     227       Over 90 Days
1.4    Yes      Quaterly  Team1  01/11/2019     -47       Overdue
1.5    Yes      6Monthly  Team1  01/11/2019     43        Within 90 Days
(BLANK ROW - ACTION CATEGORY HEADER)
2.1    Yes      Monthly   Team1  01/01/2020     -47       Overdue
2.2    Yes      Annually  Team1  01/11/2019     227       Over 90 Days
2.3    Yes      Annually  Team1  01/11/2019     227       Over 90 Days
2.4    Yes      Quaterly  Team1  01/11/2019     -47       Overdue
2.5    Yes      6Monthly  Team1  01/11/2019     43        Within 90 Days
```

Comment: please mock up some data and expected output and [edit] the post to include that in plain text so we can copy paste.

Answer (score 0):

If one has the dynamic array formula `FILTER()` then put the desired column headers in and use this formula:

```
=INDEX(FILTER($A:$G,($F:$F<=30)*($F:$F<>"")),0,MATCH(K$1,$A$1:$G$1,0))
```

And copy over:

[image]

---

If not then use this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$G,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(INDEX($A$2:$G$13,0,MATCH(K$1,$A$1:$G$1,0)))/(($F$2:$F$13<=30)*($F$2:$F$13<>"")),ROW($ZZ1)),MATCH(K$1,$A$1:$G$1,0)),"")
```

This will need to be copied/dragged down and over.

[image]

Comment: The result is exactly what I need...unfortunately I don't have the FILTER function available

Comment: Additionally, made a slight mistake on the data set- now amended in the initial question

Comment: Thanks- is it possible to replicate this across multiple sheets? The original table I posted was supposed to be solely for 'Team 1'. There would be a second sheet for 'Team 2' which would be in the exact same layout/format...